# Flutter Web with AutofillHints.creditCardNumber - Scan New Card Doesn't work in Flutter Web with Chrome for Android, but it works in Safari iPhone

Tags: flutter, web

I'm using AutofillHints.creditCardNumber on Flutter Web, everything is ok with HTTPS, it even works on iPhone. However, on Chrome Android the option to scan the card appears, then activates the camera, but does not return anything to the TextField.

If using HTML5 with cc-number it also works normal on Android Chrome to scan card with camera. The problem only happens with Flutter Web.

Has anyone gone through this?

Thanks